# react-bootstrap nav.link routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I am working on a project. I have navbar and nav.links on it. such as home, price and features.

I would like to page routing when I click it. Here is my codes about it. I did it usual routing style but it doesn't work.

```
<LinkContainer>
     <Nav.Link to="/price" >Price</Nav.Link>
</LinkContainer>
```

and my routing definations in app.js;

```
<Route path ="/price" exact component={Price}></Route>
```

I create and import price.js and also import them.

I can succesfully use routing on my buttons but nav.links doesn't work. Any idea?

*Btw it was orginally like this  `<Nav.Link href="#price" >Price</Nav.Link>`
Actually idk what is href for?So, I erased it and add "to"

Answer (score 12):

This code works for me:

`<Nav.Link as={Link} to="/home" >Home</Nav.Link>`

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake it should be;

```
<LinkContainer to="/price">
     <Nav.Link >Price</Nav.Link>
</LinkContainer>
```

I leave this question here for if someone has any problem like this.

Actually I need to learn what is href for?

Comment: href is simple html attribute and path/to is react element attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In `react-bootstrap` you need to define like this

```
<LinkContainer>
     <Nav.Link href="/price" >Price</Nav.Link>
</LinkContainer>
```

instead of

```
 <LinkContainer>
     <Nav.Link to="/price" >Price</Nav.Link>
</LinkContainer>
```

**And using `react-router-dom`**

```
<Link to="/price" >Price</Link>
```

or

```
<NavLink to="/price" >Price</NavLink>
```

Comment: Thx, please find my own answer. Is there any difference between yours? Or these are just same things with different notation?

Answer (score 0):

Try to user **`react-router-dom`** instead of **`react-router`**

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route} from "react-router-dom";
```

Prepare your render like follows, make sure your nav and route both under **`<BrowserRouter>...</BrowserRouter>`**

```
render() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <LinkContainer>
                 <Nav.Link to="/price" >Price</Nav.Link>
            </LinkContainer>
            <Route path ="/price" exact component={Price}></Route>
        <BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

**Update**

You may use also **`Link`** instead of **`Nav.Link`** like this

```
<Link to="/price">Price</Link>
```

And you just need to import it from react-router-dom

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link} from "react-router-dom";
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is for `react-bootstrap (based on BS-v3)` this used to work:

```
<Nav>
  <LinkContainer to="/routeA"><NavItem>My RouteA</NavItem></LinkContainer>
  <LinkContainer to="/routeB"><NavItem>My RouteB</NavItem></LinkContainer>
</Nav>
```

But for `react-bootstrap (based on BS-v4)`, the devs changed it to

```
<Nav>
  <LinkContainer to="/routeA"><Nav.Link>My RouteA</Nav.Link></LinkContainer>
  <LinkContainer to="/routeB"><Nav.Link>My RouteB</Nav.Link></LinkContainer>
</Nav>
```

*Note `LinkContainer` comes from `react-router-bootstrap`

[I could not find the official doco for this, and I don't know how to do a pull-request, I need Github for dummies]