# React Router: not working to route to Landing page

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use use Router to navigate through different pages. However it doesnt seem to be working. Code below is for the Navbar that uses "LINK and provides a path for the components.

```
                         <div className="middle-section-b " >
                        <Link className ="LINK"style={navStyle} to = "/">
                          <div className = "pages">Home </div>
                        </Link>

                       <Link className ="LINK" style={navStyle} to ='/about'>
                          <div className = "pages">About </div>
                       </Link>

                        <Link className ="LINK" style={navStyle} to ='/services'>
                          <div className = "pages">Services </div>
                        </Link>

                         <Link className ="LINK" style={navStyle} to ='/process'>
                          <div className = "pages">Our Process </div>
                        </Link>

                        <Link className ="LINK"className ="LINK" style={navStyle} to 
                             ='/contact'>
                          <div className = "pages">Contact </div>
                        </Link>
                

                 </div>
```

The code below is the app component. The navigation between pages is not working. I appreciate any ideas or suggestions.
function allComp() {

```
       return (
       <div>
    

     <Router>
       <Navbar className="navBar"/>  
        
                <Route path = "/" component = {MainPage}></Route>
             
                <Route path = "/contact" component ={ContactPage}></Route>
                {/* <ContactPage/> */}
                <Route path = "/about" component ={AboutPage}></Route>
                {/* <AboutPage/> */}

                <Route path ="/services" component = {ServicePage}></Route>
                {/* <ServicePage/> */}

                <Route path ="/process" component = {ProcessPage}></Route>
                {/* <ServicePage/> */}
      
    </Router>
    </div>
    )
}

 export default allComp //all components
```

Comment: Looks like a similar query is answered here. URL: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59084960/react-bootstrap-nav-link-routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59084960/react-bootstrap-nav-link-routing)

Answer (score 1):

Does its load the page or it only navigate to '/' page. Try adding `exact path= "/"` in you homepage route. Without 'exact path' in your '/' route, the site will always load at your '/' component.

Comment: Thank you @Rupak. Adding "exact" worked perfectly

Comment: Glad to help u @AhmedHassan. I request u to mark it as an answer which will help alot. Thank you